# IinearLayout.addView(TextView) doesn't work

Tags: android

I want to add `textview` to `linear layout` programmatically, So I tried with the following code but It crashes my app.

```
TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.RL);



    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
   linearLayout.addView(valueTV )   ;   

    }
}
```

Comment: You can't instantiate that `TextView` outside of a method. Move it to inside `onCreate()`. Also, you'll need to instantiate a new `TextView` for each iteration of your loop, or you'll get an `IllegalStateException`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add like below (Edited the answer) -

```
LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
TextView tv=new TextView(this);
tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
tv.setText("test");
linearLayout.addView(tv);
```

Comment: what is m_vwJokeLayout?

Comment: @JEREEF replace that with your linear layout

Comment: I get this error  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.smallapp/com.example.smallapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Simply initialize `TextView` in `onCreate()`

```
valueTV = new TextView(this);
```

Because the context is null as you declared in declaration part.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialized textview before adding in layout so carsh will be not there actually you are directly adding valueTv without initialize in scope you currently initialize out of onCreate().

```
 linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.RL);

  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
         TextView valueTV =new TextView(this); 
         valueTV .setText(i+"");
         linearLayout.addView(valueTV );   

    }
}
```